# Unexpected return - {"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null} - Stripe Request

Tags: json, react-native, react-hooks, axios, stripe-payments

I am passing this function for the request:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await axios.post(${API_BASE_URL}/payment-sheet, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
           OTHER REQUIRED HEADER...
        },
      });
      return await response.data;
 

    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERROR-AXIOS:", error)
    }

  };

  const axiosTest = async () => await fetchPaymentSheetParams();
  console.log("AXIOS-PAYMENT:PQP", axiosTest());
}, []);
```

I should receive a json with 4 elements....

However, I first receive the console of axiosTest = **{"_A": null, "_x": 0, "_y": 0, "_z": null}**

Then I receive the console of the catch error message giving **401** even passing everything the server expects to receive in the headers.

Why is the request not being successful and what suggestion would you give me to solve it? Thank you for your help in advance.

I try to receive a json with 4 valid elements but I am receiving empty elements

Comment: The issue seems to be with whatever your server returns right now. My advice is to add clear logs both before your `return await response.data;` and also on the server where you respond to ensure you return valid JSON but we can't really debug the missing code

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Henrique Nascimento's,

We are not able to use async/await in any hooks. In some case there we need it we can use IIFE(Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

So we can rewrite your code by following way.

```
useEffect(() => {
```

(() => {

```
try {
  const response = await axios.post(${API_BASE_URL}/payment-sheet, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
       OTHER REQUIRED HEADER...
    },
  });
  const responseBody = await response.data;
```

console.log("AXIOS-PAYMENT:PQP", responseBody);

```
} catch (error) {
  console.log("ERROR-AXIOS:", error)
}
```

})();

}, []);